# Heroku pg:restore fails with out of memory error

Tags: postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres

I'm attempting to restore about 1 million rows to a hobby-basic database but it keeps failing with an `out of memory` message. How can I get around this?

The dump was made following Heroku's guide https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgres-import-export#create-dump-file